# Create custom lead button to look up that leads url in the search box

Tags: custom-button

At my old company we had a custom lead button that read "Who's Working?" When you clicked the button it would run a search for url from the leads email. The point was to see all the stuff going on at that account so reps wouldn't step on each-others toes.

I have the button but just need to know what to fill in on the edit custom button page.

How can this be done in PE?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "search for url from the leads email"? Please explain

Comment: Do you possibly mean launch a report from button?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a post on how to create the button you asked about from Anthony Zhang of SalesLoft. Brilliant, I agree! http://www.salesmane.com/the-whos-working-button-in-salesforce/

Comment: Oh, I just noticed Kyle Porter asked the question, and Anthony Zhang works for your company now. Guess you already found your solution!  :)